# left div: fixed: right div fluid - minor issue css

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
.col-fixed-left {
    /* Fixed Width */
    width: 250px;

    /* Fixed Sidebar */
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;

    padding: 0px 15px;
    background: #444c63;
}
.col-fluid-right {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="col-fixed-left">
    <a href="#">Left Side</a>
</div>
<div class="col-fluid-right">
    <a href="#">Right Side</a>
</div>
```

**Issue:** The issue is, right side is getting inside the left side div because the right div is fixed. I do not want to apply margin-left: 250px(as left div is 250px wide) to appear the right div text properly on the screen. I need a good solution for this.

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bt1h68bv/)

Comment: What is wrong with using `margin-left: 250px` on `.col-fluid-right`? What other considerations are  there in the design?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible since "A fixed element does not leave a gap in the page where it would normally have been located." - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp Unless you're willing to change right div to fixed as well, but that's probably not what you want...

Comment: hmmm so i need to use the margin-left. i though there will be a better solution like display something or something else. anyways thanks

Answer (score 0):

```css
.col-fixed-left {
 /* Fixed Width */
 width: 250px;

 /* Fixed Sidebar */
 position: fixed;
 height: 100%;

 padding: 0px 15px;
 background: #444c63;
}
.col-fluid-right {
 width: 250px;
 padding: 0px 15px;
 background: #ddd;
    position: fixed;
    left:250px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-fixed-left">
    <a href="#">Left Side</a>
</div>
<div class="col-fluid-right">
    <a href="#">Right Side</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bt1h68bv/2/

Try this solitions.